# Using nanoid in Vue fails with ''Missing file extension cjs"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nanoid

I want to use nanoid in my Vue project. I tried both:

```
import nanoid from 'nanoid';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
```

but webpack fails with

```
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: Missing file extension "cjs" for "nanoid" (import/extensions) at src\components\molecules\ProfileLink.vue:18:24:
  16 | import { BPopover } from 'bootstrap-vue';
  17 | // import nanoid from 'nanoid';
> 18 | import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
```

Adding the suffix does not help either:

```
This dependency was not found
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-framework-j7gy3?file=/src/App.vue. Try the old `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install`

Comment: Thanks, it helped